# Enviroment variables react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which in development will redirect to a localhost url but in production to a different url. In my backend I have the same situation and there i solved it with a package called dotenv. I was wondering how someone would do this in a react front-end.

```
export default withRouter(function Login(props) {

    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('jwt')){
            props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
    })

    const handleLogin = () => {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/auth/google";
    }

    return (
        <LoginView handleLogin={handleLogin}/>
    )
})
```

Comment: Does redirect url returning from back end service?

Comment: I think it's achievable by doing some webpack config, there's an npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

Comment: Are the two URLs completely different or does only the domain change? Why don't you use relative paths? Or absolute paths from root `/` without specifying the domain. I am not very enthusiastic of having 'development vs. production' logic in runtime code.

Comment: Where are you redirecting from? Is it a different host to where you're redirecting to (in dev & production?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dotenv to add environment variables to react as well. During app deployment(in the build process) the environment variables must be replaced with the corresponding URLs (as this is the most frequently encountered use case in front-end applications). This can be done while configuring the build process.

Here is an example using Webpack https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5

> The whole idea here is to create a file (called just .env) filled with
>   your environment variables. To prevent people from finding out your
>   local database password is the same one you use for every single one
>   of your accounts on the internet , I urge you to add the .env file to
>   your .gitignore. Your front-end code will refer to the same
>   environment variable (process.env.API_URL) on both environments
>   (development/production), but because you defined different values in
>   your .env files, the compiled values will be different.

I would suggest having a separate .env file for the react app as it should not be accidentally served with the website.

Create React App has a module(built around the node dotenv module) you can use for adding custom environment variables

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

> The environment variables are embedded during the build time. Since
>   Create React App produces a static HTML/CSS/JS bundle, it can’t
>   possibly read them at runtime. To read them at runtime, you would need
>   to load HTML into memory on the server and replace placeholders in
>   runtime, as described here. Alternatively you can rebuild the app on
>   the server anytime you change them.

Comment: To add to this answer and on the specific use case of urls and create-react-app, you can also set the `proxy` property in your package.json as documented here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on how you are using react.

If you are using react-script, you can go will above solution(https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

But if you are using webpack, try to use DotenvPlugin in place of dotenv module (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/).

In my opinion, pls don't follow method 1 use in medium link, as env should not be push on git but package.json need to be done.